# Copying text from a textfield from one class to another. (Java)

Tags: java, swing, jframe, parameter-passing, jtextfield

So I want to use the text from a textbox in one class  in a different class, but I am having trouble passing it. I more or less want to use it in an SQL query so I can get the same user info from a different table. This is first bit is my Login class. The second is the TaskViewer class. I need the content from textFieldUN in Login to go to TaskViewer so I can access the correct user's info every time a particular one logs in. Thank you for any help! Please tell me if I am not clear, I will try to explain better. Sorry first time using this site!

```
public class Login {

private JFrame frame;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Login window = new Login();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
Connection connection = null;
private JTextField textFieldUN;
private JPasswordField passwordField;

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public Login() {
    initialize();
    connection = sqliteConnection.dbConnector(); 
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 667, 399);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Username:");
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(234, 95, 75, 27);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);

    JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Password:");
    lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(234, 162, 75, 27);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_1);

    textFieldUN = new JTextField();
    textFieldUN.setBounds(321, 95, 232, 39);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textFieldUN);
    textFieldUN.setColumns(10);


    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Login");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            try {
                String query = "SELECT * FROM  User_Info WHERE Username = ? and Password = ?"; //index 1 for UN 2 for PW
                PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query); //Must pass query
                pst.setString(1, textFieldUN.getText() ); //UN get
                pst.setString(2, passwordField.getText() ); //PW get //it is crossed put because of the password masking
                ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
                //String userNameEntered = textFieldUN.getText();



                int count = 0;
                while(rs.next()) {
                    count = count +1;
                }
                    if (count == 1)
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User name and password is correct!");
                        frame.dispose();
                        TaskViewer tskvwr = new TaskViewer();
                        tskvwr.setVisible(true);
                    }
                    else if(count > 1)
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Duplicated user name and password!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User name or password is incorrect!");
                    }
                    rs.close();
                    pst.close();
            }catch(Exception e) 
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

            }

        }

    });
    btnNewButton.setBounds(415, 244, 138, 39);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

    passwordField = new JPasswordField();
    passwordField.setBounds(321, 156, 232, 39);
    frame.getContentPane().add(passwordField);
}

}
```

---

```
public class TaskViewer extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTable table;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                TaskViewer frame = new TaskViewer();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
Connection connection = null;
public TaskViewer() {
    connection = sqliteConnection.dbConnector(); //need to connect to db
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 602, 402);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
    JButton btnLoadTable = new JButton("Load Task");
    btnLoadTable.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            try {
                 //String usernameretrieved = .UsernameRetriever()
                String query = "SELECT * FROM Task WHERE Username = ?";//I need to only get the task from a singular user from login
// WHERE I WANT TO USE THE TEXT BOX TO QUERY, I KNOW ? IS WRONG
                PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                pst.setString(1, textFieldUN.getText() );
                ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
                table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs)); //DbUtil is from rs2

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
    btnLoadTable.setBounds(34, 41, 97, 25);
    contentPane.add(btnLoadTable);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setBounds(177, 41, 376, 248);
    contentPane.add(scrollPane);

    table = new JTable();
    scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
}
}
```

---

```
public class sqliteConnection {

        Connection conn = null;
        public static Connection dbConnector()
        {
            try {
                Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\a pathway
                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection is up and running!");
                return  conn;
            }catch(Exception e) 
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
                return null; 
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: You have two main classes here. I would consider a restructure so that you have one main class that first displays the login frame, stores the user credentials that you're going to need to re-reference as class variables (username, for example) and then displays your TaskViewer frame.

Comment: This was pre-generated by eclipse with window builder. I would not be able to make the buttons and event listeners so well without this unfortunately. Is there perhaps a way to just pass it to that one spot I need? or is there something I can do in the query itself? I may try a restructure after I exhaust those option, but so far the separate class has been helpful when dividing up frames/windows. COuld you explain further why it would help, or show what you would do? (This is not homework or anything)

Comment: Because there are two mains, you are essentially running two entirely different applications. There should only be one main class per application. I'm not an eclipse user, but generally there should be an option in an IDE to create a new JPanel within your project, which is probably more what you're after.

Comment: Is there any way you can show a quick way of how you would do it? I do better by looking and learning. Because it would be nice to ask question about specific reasonings of why you did particular things as compared to others.

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: I appreciate the knowledge. I was mostly following a tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you found your solution but I thought perhaps you may find this useful. It seems to me you just need a login (User Name & Password) input mechanism and once you have that information you can deal with it accordingly. For this case (in my opinion) the easiest way to deal with a Login scenario is to utilize a custom modal dialog. Before the application becomes visible the Login must be satisfied and how things are satisfied is up to you and your code. All you need is the means for a User to supply a name and password to work with for validation before your application falls into view. That's generally how it always works anyways:

[image: Login Dialog]

And here is the runnable code which contains the method that generates and displays the above Login Dialog window. The code is your own **TaskView** Class with some modifications to it and methods added. **The Login Class has been eliminated altogether here** but your **sqliteConnection** class remains the same with the exception that it was renamed to **SQLiteConnection**:

```
/*
  In this modified example, the Database connection is opened 
  and closed before and after every DB access operation. I don't
  think Connection Pooling is required here....yet.

  The image used in the Login Dialog can be downloaded from here:
             https://www.freeiconspng.com/img/3059
*/

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TaskViewer extends JFrame {

    // Class global member variables
    private String applicationUserName;         // Will hold the logged in User      Name.
    private String applicationUserPassword;     // Will hold the Logged in User Password.

    // Constructor
    public TaskViewer() {
        // Keep it tidy and simple.
        initializeTaskViewer();
    }

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new TaskViewer().startApp(); // Don't need static methods this way.
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void startApp() {
        /* 
          View the TaskView application window. The Event Dispatch 
          Thread (EDT) doesn't actually let this happen until this 
          method is finished so, all you will see is the Login Dialog
          when the application starts and validation is satisfied.
          Since we extend JFrame in this Class, we don't have to 
          instantiate as new TaskView. Doing so will just wipe out the
          class member variables we had set with our Login Dialog 
          since it would now be a new instance of TaskView.
        */
        setVisible(true);
        String message = "<html>Please supply your Login information. If "
                + "you are<br>a New User then you will be automatically added<br>"
                + "to the database.<br><br><br>";
        String title = "TaskView - User Login ...";
        String userNameCaption = null; //"User Name:";
        String passwordCaption = null; //"Password:";
        String footNoteCaption = "<html><pre><font size=2>                  "
                + "Select <font color=red>Cancel</font> to quit</font></pre><br></html>";
        Color backColor = Color.decode("#ffe6cc");  // our custom background color.
        //Object dialogImage = JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE;  // You can do it this way...
        // or this way...
        Object dialogImage = "login-icon-3059.png|80,80";  // get image from: https://www.freeiconspng.com/img/3059
        // The text captions for our dialog buttons
        Object[] buttonCaptions = {"<html><font color=red>Login</font> To TaskView</html>",
            "<html><font color=red>Cancel</font> - Quit</html>"};

        // The call to our Custom Login Dialog
        String[] loginPass = customLoginInputBox(null, message, title, userNameCaption, passwordCaption,
                footNoteCaption, backColor, dialogImage, buttonCaptions);
        /* The call could very well look like this...
           String[] loginPass = customLoginInputBox(null, message, title, null, null, null, null, null, null);
           ...but the dialog looks pretty bland ;p  */

        if (loginPass[0] == null) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Login Not Supplied! Quiting...",
                    "Invalid Login", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else {
            applicationUserName = loginPass[0];
            applicationUserPassword = loginPass[1];
        }

        boolean valid = validateLogin(applicationUserName, applicationUserPassword);
        if (!valid) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    private void initializeTaskViewer() {
        setTitle("TaskView v1.0.0");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 602, 402);
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        JTable table = new JTable();
        JButton btnLoadTable = new JButton("Load Tasks");
        btnLoadTable.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                Connection connection = null;
                try {
                    connection = SQLiteConnection.dbConnector();
                    String query = "SELECT * FROM Task WHERE Username = ?";
                    PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                    pst.setString(1, applicationUserName); 
                    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
                    // Don't need dependency on DbUtil with this provided small method.
                    resultSetToJTable(table, rs); 
                    //table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs)); //DbUtil is from rs2
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    Logger.getLogger(TaskViewer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
                }
                finally {
                    try { 
                        // Closeing the connection will automatically 
                        // close pst and rs.
                        if (connection != null) { connection.close(); }
                    }
                    catch (SQLException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(TaskViewer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        btnLoadTable.setBounds(34, 41, 100, 25);
        contentPane.add(btnLoadTable);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        scrollPane.setBounds(177, 41, 376, 248);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane);
        // Set Appplication window in center of screen.
        // Must be done just before setVisible() is used.
        setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
    }

    /**
     * Displays a modal Custom Input Dialog Box where a User Name and Password
     * can be supplied.
     *
     * @param component             (Component) The parent component from where
     *                              the dialog will be displayed from. Null can
     *                              be supplied if there is no apparent parent
     *                              component. If null is supplied then a parent
     *                              is temporarily created to ensure visibility
     *                              and then disposed of when done.<br>
     *
     * @param message               (String) The message body to display within
     *                              the Login Dialog. The length of the message
     *                              strings (before and after line breaks) can
     *                              determine how large the dialog will become.
     *                              The use of line breaks can be pertinent
     *                              here. HTML can be used to create your
     *                              message.<br>
     *
     * @param title                 (String) The title to be displayed within
     *                              the Login Dialog window title bar. Only
     *                              plain text can be used here.<br>
     *
     * @param userNameBoxCaption    (String) The User Name entry text box
     *                              contains a text caption to the left of it so
     *                              as to indicate what the entry box is for. By
     *                              default this caption states: "User Name:".
     *                              If you want to change this default caption
     *                              then you can supply it here. If you prefer
     *                              to use the default then simply supply null.
     *                              HTML can be used here.<br>
     *
     * @param passwordBoxCaption    (String) The Password entry text box
     *                              contains a text caption to the left of it so
     *                              as to indicate what the entry box is for. By
     *                              default this caption states: "Password:". If
     *                              you want to change this default caption then
     *                              you can supply it here. If you prefer to use
     *                              the default then simply supply null. HTML
     *                              can be used here.<br>
     *
     * @param dialogFootNoteCaption (string) By default there is no footer
     *                              caption. The footer text caption is
     *                              displayed below and between the Password
     *                              entry box and the dialog buttons located at
     *                              the bottom of the dialog. Any additional
     *                              information can be supplied here if desired.
     *                              HTML can be used here as well.<br>
     *
     * @param dialogBackColor       (Color) You can set the desired background
     *                              color for your Login Dialog. By default is
     *                              would be the default Message Box color for
     *                              your specific Operating System or to
     *                              whatever Look & Feel currently being used by
     *                              your application. Any color can be supplied
     *                              as long as it is supplied as a Color
     *                              Object.<br>
     *
     * @param dialogImage           (Object) This parameter is a little special.
     *                              By default a standard JOptionPane Question
     *                              Message icon is displayed to the left side
     *                              of the Login Dialog. If you want to change
     *                              this icon to any one of the other
     *                              JOptionPane Icons then you can simply supply
     *                              any one of them here in the form of:<pre>
     *
     *      JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE;
     *      JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE
     *      JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE
     *      JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE
     *      JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE</pre><br>
     *
     * If however you want to utilize your own custom image (transparent
     * background .png is best) then you can supply the path and file name of
     * your image to this parameter as string. You can also optionally preset a
     * specific size for your image by placing a Pipe (|) delimiter at the end
     * of the path string and supplying integer values for width and height, for
     * example:
     * <pre>
     *
     *     "C:\\My App Path\\Images\\logo.png|80,80"</pre><br>
     *
     * In the example image path string above we're telling the method to resize
     * the image to 80 pixels wide by 80 pixels high. The delimiter used to
     * separate the Width and Height in the above path string is a comma (,) but
     * can very well be a whitespace, a semicolon (;), or a colon (:). Any one
     * of the four will work as a Width/Height delimiter.<br><br>
     *
     * This parameter will accept either a integer value or a string value. If a
     * integer value is supplied then it will be assumed that a JOptionPane icon
     * is supplied. If a string value is supplied then it will be assumed that
     * it is the path to a custom image file located within the local file
     * system.<br>
     *
     * @param dialogButtonCaptions  (Single Dimensional (1D) Object[] Array)
     *                              There are only two buttons within the Login
     *                              Dialog and by default they are the "OK" and
     *                              "Cancel" buttons (cancel has default focus).
     *                              Both by default contain the aforementioned
     *                              respective text captions. If you want to
     *                              change these button captions then you can do
     *                              so here by supplying a object array of
     *                              button caption strings, for example:<pre>
     *
     *      Object[] buttonCaptions = {"Login To App", "Cancel/Quit"};</pre><br>
     *
     * HTML can be used in the caption strings.<br>
     *
     * @return (Single Dimensional (1D) String[] Array) The returned string
     *         array will only ever contain two specific elements, the supplied
     *         Login Name and the supplied Password. If null in either or both
     *         elements is returned then the dialog was canceled (right-most
     *         button selected) or the dialog was closed with the dialog window
     *         close [x] button. The dialog can not be closed unless proper
     *         credentials (name and password) are supplied or the dialog is
     *         canceled.
     */
    public String[] customLoginInputBox(Component component, String message, String title,
            String userNameBoxCaption, String passwordBoxCaption,
            String dialogFootNoteCaption, Color dialogBackColor,
            Object dialogImage, Object[] dialogButtonCaptions) {
        String[] result = {null, null};
        Object[] buttonCaptions = {"OK", "Cancel"};
        if (dialogButtonCaptions != null && dialogButtonCaptions.length > 0) {
            buttonCaptions = Arrays.copyOf(dialogButtonCaptions, dialogButtonCaptions.length);
        }
        Component comp = component;
        JFrame iFRAME = new JFrame();
        if (comp == null) {
            /* Create a dummy JFrame. This is done so that
               the Dialog box that is used in the application
               does not hide behind the IDE or ON TOP form if 
               null is used for the parent component. Not a 
               problem for some. 
             */
            iFRAME.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
            comp = iFRAME;
        }

        String userNameCaption = "User Name: ";  // Default caption
        if (userNameBoxCaption != null && !userNameBoxCaption.equals("")) {
            userNameCaption = userNameBoxCaption;
        }
        String passwordCaption = "Password:  "; // Default caption
        if (passwordBoxCaption != null && !passwordBoxCaption.equals("")) {
            passwordCaption = passwordBoxCaption;
        }
        // Default dialog footnote (no footnote).
        String footNote = dialogFootNoteCaption == null
                || dialogFootNoteCaption.equals("") ? " " : dialogFootNoteCaption;

        String uName = "";
        String passWrd = "";

        // Set dialog background to white. 
        Color origPanelColor = (Color) UIManager.get("OptionPane.background");
        Color origPaneBackgroundColor = (Color) UIManager.get("Panel.background");
        if (dialogBackColor != null) {
            try {
                 UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
                UIManager.put("OptionPane.background", dialogBackColor);
                UIManager.put("Panel.background", dialogBackColor);
            }
            catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger("customLoginInputBox() Method Error!").log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        // Get User input as to User Name and Password.
        // using a custom Input Dialog...
        // Build the Login dialog Panel...
        BorderLayout layout = new BorderLayout();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(layout);
        panel.setBackground(dialogBackColor);
        JLabel label = new JLabel(message);
        panel.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
        p.setBackground(dialogBackColor);
        JPanel labels = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 2, 2));
        labels.setBackground(dialogBackColor);
        labels.add(new JLabel(userNameCaption, SwingConstants.RIGHT));
        labels.add(new JLabel(passwordCaption, SwingConstants.RIGHT));
        p.add(labels, BorderLayout.WEST);
        JPanel controls = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 2, 2));
        controls.setBackground(dialogBackColor);
        JTextField userName = new JTextField();
        controls.add(userName);

        JPasswordField password = new JPasswordField();
        controls.add(password);
        p.add(controls, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(p);
        JLabel baseLabel = new JLabel(footNote);
        panel.add(baseLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        // The custom Image to use in Login dialog...
        ImageIcon icon = null;
        int msgType = JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE;
        if (dialogImage != null && dialogImage.getClass().getSimpleName().toUpperCase().equals("STRING")) {
            String dString = dialogImage.toString();
            int sizeWidth = 0, sizeHeight = 0;
            if (dString.contains("|")) {
                String[] dsTmp = dString.split("\\|");
                dString = dsTmp[0];
                if (dsTmp[1].contains(",") || dsTmp[1].contains(";")
                       || dsTmp[1].contains(":") || dsTmp[1].contains(" ")) {
                    try {
                        sizeWidth = Integer.parseInt(dsTmp[1].split(",|;|:|\\s+")[0]);
                        sizeHeight = Integer.parseInt(dsTmp[1].split(",|;|:|\\s+")[1]);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            }
            icon = new ImageIcon(dString);
            if (sizeWidth == 0) {
                sizeWidth = icon.getIconWidth();
            }
            if (sizeHeight == 0) {
                sizeHeight = icon.getIconHeight();
            }
            Image image = icon.getImage();

            // Size it to what you want (this example uses: 128 x 128).
            Image newimg = image.getScaledInstance(sizeWidth, sizeHeight, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            icon = new ImageIcon(newimg);
        }
        else if (dialogImage != null && dialogImage.getClass().getSimpleName().toUpperCase().equals("INTEGER")) {
            msgType = (int) dialogImage;
        }
        // Get Input from User. This will display 
        // your custom Input Dialog Box.
        while (uName.equals("") || passWrd.equals("")) {
            int res = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(iFRAME, panel, title,
                    JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, msgType, icon, buttonCaptions, buttonCaptions[1]);

            // Process the result from our custom Input Dialog Box
            if (res == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION && !userName.getText().equals("")
                    && !Arrays.toString(password.getPassword()).equals("")) {
                uName = userName.getText();
                char[] pass = password.getPassword();
                for (int i = 0; i < pass.length; i++) {
                    passWrd += Character.toString(pass[i]);
                }
                if (uName.equals("") || passWrd.equals("")) {
                    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
                    continue;
                }
                // Do whatever you want with User Name and Password
                result[0] = uName;
                result[1] = passWrd;
            }
            else {
                if (res == 1 || res == -1) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        iFRAME.dispose(); // Dispose of the temp parent for the dialog.

        // Set UI Colors back to original. 
        if (dialogBackColor != null) {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
                UIManager.put("OptionPane.background", origPanelColor);
                UIManager.put("Panel.background", origPaneBackgroundColor);
            }
            catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger("customLoginInputBox() Method Error!").log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private boolean validateLogin(String userName, String userPassword) {
        boolean isValid = false;
        Connection connection = SQLiteConnection.dbConnector();
        try {
            String query = "SELECT * FROM  User_Info WHERE Username = ? and Password = ?";
            try (PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {
                pst.setString(1, userName);
                pst.setString(2, userPassword);
                try (ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery()) {
                    int count = 0;
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        if (rs.getString("Username").equals(userName) && 
                                rs.getString("Password").equals(userPassword)) {
                            isValid = true;
                            break;  // don't need loop any more
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (isValid) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "User name and password is correct!", 
                            "Login Valid", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }
                else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "User name or password is incorrect!",
                            "Login Invalid!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    // You may want to add a mechanism to add new User to database here.
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
        finally {
            try { 
                if (connection != null) { connection.close(); }
            }
            catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(TaskViewer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        return isValid;
    }

    /**
     * Fills the supplied JTable with the Column Names and Data from a supplied
     * ResultSet.<br><br>
     *
     * @param table (JTable) The variable name of the JTable to fill.<br>
     *
     * @param rs    (ResultSet) The ResultSet to fill JTable from.
     */
    public void resultSetToJTable(JTable table, ResultSet rs) {
        try {
            DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
            ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
            int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();

            for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++) {
                tableModel.addColumn(metaData.getColumnLabel(columnIndex));
            }
            Object[] row = new Object[columnCount];
            while (rs.next()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
                    row[i] = rs.getObject(i + 1);
                }
                tableModel.addRow(row);
            }
            table.setModel(tableModel);
        }
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println("resultSetToJTable() Method Error! - "
                    + System.lineSeparator() + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Copy and paste the code above into a **new project** and also add your **SQLiteConnection** Class with the proper database information then run the application to see how it works. Don't forget to also add the SQLite JDBC Driver library to this new project.

Do take note, although done here, Passwords should never be stored in their plain-text form but instead a hash of that password should be stored instead. No one but the User should ever know what his or her password might be. It should be a hash (with a salt) of the supplied password being compared to a hash that is stored within the database table. Not even you should ever know the password. Look into using BCrypt or [jBCrypt](https://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/). The small code snippet in the link shows how easy it is to use. And, you already know about informing a User that the entered name and password has already been used, that's a dead give-away.

Comment: I wish I could give you soooooooo many up votes. This was super descriptive, and super useful. I really appreciate that. Plus the extra knowledge is awesome. I will try to play around with extensively. I appreciate this greatly. Thank you for the time you put into this. From what I could tell from lolynns's response that a custom modal dialog is best. Between you two I have actually learned a great deal.

You would probable make excellent tutorial videos.

Comment: Also could you say more about why the pros and cons of using the custom modal dialog is a better choice compared to others? I can see immediate benefits, but I just want a more thorough understanding.

Comment: If you can avoid using multiple JFrames then it's a good idea to do so. The main thing is that JDialogs can be made to be **Modal** meaning the dialog has complete focus and no other window in your application can take that away unless the use of the dialog has completed and the dialog is closed. **JOptionPane** dialogs are all **modal**. [Andrew Thompson's post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/4725875) sums up the topic quite nicely and is well worth reading.

Comment: Thank you. You have been very helpful! I was new to the whole login stuff when I started Saturday haha

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple application. Here I use a JDialog to display my login panel, and keep program control until the user has successfully logged in.

```
public class LoginPanel extends JPanel {

private String userName = null;
private JDialog dialog;

public LoginPanel(JDialog d) {
    dialog = d;
    // call initialize method to build your GUI here
    // don't forget to attach the ActionListener methods to the correct buttons
}

private void closeWindow() {
    dialog.dispose();
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

private void okButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String userInput = userNameTextField.getText();
    // validate user input here

    // if it's good, set username variable and call closeWindow
    userName = userInput;
    closeWindow();
}                                        

private void cancelButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    userName = null;
    closeWindow();
} 
}
```

Then this is your main application JFrame with the main class

```
public class TaskViewer extends JFrame {

private static String userName = null;

public TaskViewer() {
    // call initialize method that builds your GUI here
    // don't forget to attach the formWindowOpened WindowListener to your JFrame
}

private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
    initLogin();
}                                 

public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new TaskViewer().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

public void initLogin() {
    JDialog dialog = new JDialog(this, "Login", 
        Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL); /* this modality setting will keep
                                                   focus on the dialog until the OK
                                                   or Cancel button is clicked */
    LoginPanel login = new LoginPanel(dialog);
    dialog.add(login);
    dialog.pack();
    dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(this);
    dialog.setVisible(true);// this passes control to your dialog window

    // program will resume here once the dialog is destroyed
    userName = login.getUserName();
    if(userName == null) {
        // do error checking here
    } else {
        // you're good, let's use the program!
    }
}
}
```

A side note about security: you should never report an error message to a user that what they entered was a duplicate username and password because you just told them another user's name and password...

Comment: I appreciate your time, let me attempt to work on it tomorrow, so I can comeback with further questions! Also yes, I was thinking of implementing something like a textbox that stated something like "username not available." I have not tweaked the performance yet. I just wanted something built and the enhance it from there, but I am glad you said it anyway, it is good advice, I appreciate it! Thank you for your time, so far!

Comment: I also have a class to connect to a database. I need to edit and put it on here.

Comment: Where are you trying to edit? You should be able to edit your own post. There's a little gray 'edit' button at the bottom of the original post.

Comment: I ended up figuring it out. More or less I needed to pass it to a user class outside my other classes right before dispose(); I then passed like so:
 `try {
     String query = "SELECT * FROM Task WHERE username = '" + user.getUserName()+"';" ;//I need to only get the task from a singular user from login
     PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
     ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
     table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs)); //DbUtil is from rs2
     
    } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }`

Comment: Your suggestion made it easier to see some things. This is my first bit of code I have done, after taking a year and a half break. I appreciate your help!